# Adding UIPickerView and UIDatePickerView - in a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I have a UITableViewController where I want to display a date picker when a row is selected and a pickerview when another row is selected (I plan to hide the other when one is displayed).

I am having trouble adding the datepicker and picker view in the story board.  I can add one and make it work fine.  But I can't drag the second one in the view. (I was able to add on top of the table view but I don't want that.)

To go around the problem, I thought I will add the other picker programmatically and assign the same frame, but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions on what may be preventing me from adding a datepicker and picker view to a UITableviewcontroller?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646822/uipickerview-in-uitableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use UViewController and add UITableView, UIPickerView and UIDatePickerView